# Which Event do I need after DataGridrow is added to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a DataGrid and canUserAddRows=true and an ObservableCollection. I want something like a validation for the ObservableCollection. So user add a row and before it gets to the ObservableCollection, I want to check the data...

I have tried RowEditEnding-Event, but when this event is fired, the new row isn't add to the ObservableCollection at this time.

Another try is the CollectionChanged-Event fromt the ObservableCollection itself but for some reason this doesn't fire... I know I could use a validation for DataBinding but there should be a way over events, or?

I am using .NET 3.5 and WPF.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It becomes very straight forward if your objects inherit from IEditableObject.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to perform data validation when using WPF. None of them are particularly quick to implement. I personally tend to prefer implementing either the [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces on my data items.

You can also use the [`ValidationRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx) class on your `Binding`s. However, for a complete validation example with the `DataGrid`, you can also refer to the [How to: Implement Validation with the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.